# Firebase invalid api key error in console

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, electron

I use Firebase-auth for my web application I'm developing with electron framework. I created an API key using project settings, and copied it into my html's body as it is suggested in Firebase guide. However, when I open the HTML page on the browser, console shows the following error.

```
code: "auth/invalid-api-key"
message: "Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly."
__proto__: Error
```

Bottom part of the body of the HTML page is as follows.

```
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.2/firebase.js"></script>
          <script>
            // Initialize Firebase
            var config = {
              apiKey: "AIzaSyAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXjILO32ZDxRKY",
              authDomain: "jumbleup-773da.firebaseapp.com",
              databaseURL: "https://jumbleup-773da.firebaseio.com",
              projectId: "jumbleup-773da",
              storageBucket: "jumbleup-773da.appspot.com",
              messagingSenderId: "971123072180"
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
          </script>
```

Note: I obfuscated the real key by changing 20 digits of it by X.

Comment: is it script in your main process ?

Comment: I use this piece of code, in index.html which in turn calls renderer.js

Comment: Try to write in render.js and append this js file in index.html

Comment: I got this error because my .env file containing my firebase api key had somehow gotten deleted.

Answer (score 8):

> Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly

This error can be showed for many reasons. I want to explain how I resolved this issue.

Firstly, I copied firebaseConfig variable clicking copy button for my website and kept it under my source folder making a file named `firebase.config.js`.

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'AIzaSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    authDomain: 'fir-axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    projectId: 'fir-axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    storageBucket: 'fir-axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    messagingSenderId: '106xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    appId: '1:1064xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
};
```

Secondly, I called firebaseConfig variable by importing it in my `App.js` file.

```
import { firebaseConfig } from './firebase.config';
```

Finally, I used this variable in this line below.

```js
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

If you get something helpful from this solution please press on upvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

For those using Next.js, you need to preface each env var with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all install firebase and then
Import firebase at first as `import firebase from 'firebase';` or in js script.
The below code is used to connect the app to firebase this includes the id and all the details to connect firebase.

```
const config ={

    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "app.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://app.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "XXXXXX2",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "5..........",
    appId: "1:52807............."
}

firebase.initializeApp(config);
export default firebase;
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using React.
I was also getting the same error because in my .env file I had `,` present after the declaration.

Before:
`REACT_APP_API_KEY="AIXXXXXXXXXXXX",`

After:
`REACT_APP_API_KEY="AIXXXXXXXXXXXX"`

Answer (score 2):

After firebase configuration like this :

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey:process.env.REACT_APP_apiKey,
    authDomain:process.env.REACT_APP_authDomain,
    projectId:process.env.REACT_APP_projectId,
    storageBucket:process.env.REACT_APP_storageBucket,
    messagingSenderId:process.env.REACT_APP_messagingSenderId,
    appId:process.env.REACT_APP_appId,
}
```

You may stop the server by Ctrl + c => y and again run the server (npm start). It will work.
I'm also getting such error and after following this my code running well. You may try, hope it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar error. How I Solve it:
I saw this when I created a .env file in the react project. it needs to restart the app again and everything works perfectly.
So the Solution is, Press Ctrl + c then y and again start it npm start or whatever you used.

Answer (score 1):

## There are two Solutions for those using React with .env:

```js
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};
```

#### 1. Put quotes on all environmental variables:

```js
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN",
  projectId: "process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
  appId: "process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID",
};
```

#### 2. Restart the Server and it will accept env variables without quotes:

```
ctrl + C
yarn start / npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: "AIzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "chxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "chxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "chxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "1:7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "G-xxxxxxxxx"
  }
};
```

add this in your environment.ts

Answer (score 0):

First of all...

1. Make sure that you copied the key correctly.
2. If you are confirmed you copied correctly and rest of the stuffs are ok but still Error is showing...
3. then just close all of your files and log out from you Gmail account
4. and then Login again and open your files and folder.

Hopefully it will work.
In my case... it worked as I said.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vite with Firebase,use the following pattern

```
  const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: import.meta.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: import.meta.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just add "export" keyword before const your job is done.

Example:

export const config ={

```
apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
authDomain: "app.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://app.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "XXXXXX2",
storageBucket: "XXXXXX.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "5..........",
appId: "1:52807............."
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error but the reason ended up being because I forgot to update my Vercel environment variables as opposed to only my local .env file.

Once I populated the Vercel environment variables, the error went away.

You can add or remove variables at this URL:

[https://vercel.com/<team_name>/<project_name>/settings/environment-variables](https://vercel.com)

Answer (score 0):

## When using .env for firebase config

Generally avoid [reserved env names](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#reserved-names), including anything that starts with `FIREBASE_`

## When using NextJS & .env:

All variables that are required for client-side firebase need to be prefixed by `NEXT_PUBLIC_` e.g. `NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_API_KEY`

**CAREFUL**: avoid prefixing the firebase-admin config variables with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`, like you private key, as these would otherwise be leaked to the client.

Answer (score -1):

- If you are using react, make sure **.env** file should be in root folder.
- .env file should not be in **src** folder.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35404147)